# How to add fonts to angular2-webpack-starter

Tags: angular, fonts, webpack

I'm trying to bind a font called "Courgette" to the [Angular Dev Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)

[image]

1. I added the font file as you see on the top left
2. I added the path to the style.css as you can see on the top right

> Now for the production, all the assets need to be generated in the
>   "web" folder

So I'll change the path of the generated files, and the public path

[image]

And at last generate and watch the files.

```
npm run build:prod -- --watch
```

Now as you can see all the files are linked to the right path in the application except for the fonts :(

[image]

For some reason it generates a path that contains the public path twice